# MATLAB: FFT with specified modes

Tags: matlab, fft

Using MATLAB I want to implement some kind of a spectral method. The idea is as following (described for a example which is working).

1. Dirichlet (and Neumann, and periodic) boundaries leads to eigenvalues in the fourier space of **`k=n*pi/L`**
2. Projecting all the linear operators in the fourier space to the discretized k-values:

   e.g. **`L = -D*(k.*k)`** (for diffusion only)
3. Defining the propagator in time as **`P = exp( dt * L )`**
4. Calculating iteratively the evolution in time by **`uh_{n+1} = uh_n * P`**
5. return the calculated value to the real space every time I want to save the value by **`ifft( uh )`**

My question concerns another boundary conditions.

In my case I have Robin boundary conditions. So, the eigenvalues are defined through some weird equation of the form **`tan( x ) = x`** or the like. The problem of computing them is solved.

As I have the values, the step no. 2 and 3 is simple too, **but**:

For applying `P` on the fourier-transformed vector `uh` I have to ensure that my **`uh = fft(u)`** uses *the same* eigenvalues, **which is not the case by default.**

By default MATLAB uses equidistant modes for the fft.

**Is there any simple trick for this?**

Or, maybe, do I have any mistake in my thoughts?